# Selenium cannot click tab in magento module detail page

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid

I'm trying to validate data using selenium version 1.0.9 in magento grid and its detail page.

First, I walked through Selenium IDE from login page to module detail page and click the tabs available there. Eventually, IDE generates PHP codes so I put the code into proper location.

Note: Here, I have clicked the two tabs so that the events get recorded into selenium IDE.

Then, I run the code from command prompt using following command:

```
phpunit --configuration /var/www/tests/phpunit_test.xml
```

I got the error (something like):

```
ERROR: Element //a[@id='test_tabs_form_section']/span not found.
```

I modified the code and tried to open the detail page before executing click to above link i.e. "test_tabs_form_section", I am getting same error.

Another strange this is if I verify any text of detail page and remove the code that calls  click to module detail tabs, it is works, not sure why?

But I really want to open detail page and click to tab, get forms element values using xpath and validate the data.

Can somebody help me, please?

Any help or suggestion is highly appreciable!

Looking forward to hear from stackoverflow geeks!

Thanks

Comment: Btw who do u think stackover flow is??

Comment: Why dnt u see what is happening when the test is running to see what page u r at when the assert is being done

Comment: Just some notes on this since this is something I am familiar with.  Magento's admin pages are a collection of a bunch of tabs that are mostly loaded by javascript.  So when you click each tab, it just shows the HTML content for that tab, and no request or response is fired since it was already loaded.

Problem here is that the Selenium IDE (firefox plugin?) doesnt seem to record the clicks if a request and response does not happen?  Am I mistaken?  Dgento is coding the clicks by hand, and seems to be having a hard time finding the elements this way.

Comment: @zzzz

it is selenium 1.0.9

yes, I have seen  running the test case, it doesn't go to the detail page. As I said before also, the code is generated from IDE just walking to detail page and clicking the tabs there. However, it gives me error message whenI execute the code.

Please let me know if you want anything more from me!

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps anybody:

- I found out more things work if firebug is active. This actually makes sense cause firebug will show the final DOM tree in all it's debugging screens, so it's possible selenium is now able to reconstruct the element path because firebug altered the internal DOM.
- If something doesn't work with the default element selection created by Selenium IDE, try switching it over to xpath:id-relative. You're already using that in your question, so maybe you there's an even better selector or you will need to resort to using clickAt instead of click.